# Polymer: Using app-indexeddb-mirror with app-pouchdb-document

Tags: html, polymer-1.0, indexeddb, web-component, pouchdb

[This page](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-storage) in the Polymer docs mentions

> Since PouchDB can automatically synchronize data with a local IndexedDB database, it has never been easier to add offline-first data access to your progressive web app.

I'm pretty new to Indexeddb and pouchdb, and am having a hard time actually putting this into practice. My code so far:

```
    <iron-ajax
        auto
        url="../data/some_data.json"
        handle-as="json"
        last-response="{{liveData}}">
    </iron-ajax>

    <app-indexeddb-mirror
        key="thedata"
        data="{{liveData}}">
    </app-indexeddb-mirror>

    <app-pouchdb-document
        id="pouchdb"
        db-name="data"
        doc-id="thedata"
        data="{{storedData}}">
    </app-pouchdb-document>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{storedData}}" as="item">
      <div>[[item.name]]</div>
    </template>
```

The above doesn't work. And printing all documents of the pouchdb comes up empty. Can someone provide a working example? Or at least clarify the relationship between these two elements?

Answer (score 0):

Pouchdb uses IndexDB directly, so you don't need to use app-indexdb-mirror.